# Generating and using a secret in a config file for JWT

Tags: node.js, security, express, authentication, jwt

I have a question regarding secrets for JWT.

I understand the "best practice" is storing the secret in an environment variable, but what about this setup?

I am generating my secret using a library called [`secrets`](http://npmjs.org/hellotoby/secrets).

I am storing my secret in a config file, and the relevant line looks like this

```
jwtSecret: process.env.JWT_SECRET || secret,
```

where `secret = new Secret(32, true, true).generate();`

Now, the way I understand this is that with this setup, my secret will be regenerated every time the server starts, essentially invalidating all previous tokens. Is this a sound setup? Is there any way that this setup will cause unnecessary grievances for my users beyond requiring them to re-authenticate? What about for me? What headaches might I face using a setup like this? I should point out that this application will likely only ever be running on one server at a time, so sharing that secret amongst multiple nodes is not a problem in my situation.

Oh and if it turns out that this is a wildly bad idea, please make it plainly evident by responding in all caps (I'm only joking, but please do make it evident).

Comment: This could making scaling exruciatingly painful. Imagine having 2 servers that both take requests equally with different secrets forcing users to re-auth everytime a request hits the server that the user isnt keyed on

Comment: @Derek right, but as I said this wouldn't be an issue in my specific situation. Thank you though for the input. Your comment along with the answer below I think have answered this for me. I'll probably change my setup to use a single, static key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you don't need (and should not) to generate secrets every time you start your server. You can just add one to your environment and that's enough.
But If you want badly to generate a secret instead of coming up with one, you can write a separate script that can be called on demand, and only by an admin behind authentication.

```
//maybe some authentication code here
process.env.secret = new Secret(32, true, true).generate();
```